Flutter Bloc Listener Not Detecting New States and Failing to Update Map Markers
I’m using flutter_bloc in a Flutter application to manage the state of a GoogleMap. The BlocListener is responsible for reacting to state changes emitted by a Cubit, such as new student locations or stop markers. However, when the Cubit emits a new state, the BlocListener does not detect the state change, and the information on the map (e.g., markers) does not update as expected.
• When the Cubit emits new states like MapStateSuccess or MapStateSuccessStops, the BlocListener should detect the change and trigger updates to the map markers.
• The BlocListener only respond to new states emitted by the Cubit when the screen is built. As a result, the map markers are not updated later on, even though the state changes are logged in the console.
What I Have Tried:
• Verified that the Cubit emits the correct states.
• Confirmed that the BlocListener is correctly attached to the Cubit.
• Used setState to update the map markers when a state is detected.
• Created another state (MapStateIdle) to be emitted in between listener completions.
Relevant methods from my MapStateCubit
void showMap() {
    User? user;
    getUserPersistentUseCase.call().then((result) {
      result.fold(
            (failure) {
          // Handle error and emit a failure state
          emit(MapStateFailure("Error al obtener la información del usuario"));
          return;
        },
            (user) {
              List<StudentModel> studentModels = [];
              GetStudentsStopsRequest request = GetStudentsStopsRequest(school: "COLEGIO NOGALES", familyCode: user.familyCode);
              logger.info("Request: ${request.toJson()}");
              getStudentsUseCase.call(params: request).then((result) {
                logger.info(result.toString());
                result.fold(
                      (failure) {
                    // Handle error and emit a failure state
                    emit(MapStateFailure("Error al obtener la lista de estudiantes: ${failure.message}"));
                  },
                      (students) {
                    studentModels = students.map((student) {
                      return StudentModel.fromEntity(student);
                    }).toList();
                  },
                );

                if (studentModels.isEmpty){
                  emit(MapStateFailure("No se encontraron estudiantes"));
                }
                else{
                  emit(MapStateSuccess(studentModels));
                  emit(MapStateIdle());
                }
              }).catchError((e) {
                // Catch unexpected errors
                emit(MapStateFailure("Error inesperado: ${e.toString()}"));
              });
            },
      );
    }).catchError((e) {
      // Catch unexpected errors
      emit(MapStateFailure("Error inesperado: ${e.toString()}"));
      return;
    });


  }
  
  void showParadas(StudentModel paradas) {
    emit(MapStateLoadingStops());
   getParadasUseCase.call(params: paradas).then((result) {
      logger.info(result.toString());
      result.fold(
            (failure) {
          // Handle error and emit a failure state
          emit(MapStateFailure("Error al obtener la lista de paradas: ${failure.message}"));
        },
            (paradas) {
          emit(MapStateSuccessStops(paradas));
          emit(MapStateIdle());
        },
      );
    }).catchError((e) {
      // Catch unexpected errors
      emit(MapStateFailure("Error inesperado: ${e.toString()}"));
    });
  }

Methods in MapScreen
void showMap() {
    User? user;
    getUserPersistentUseCase.call().then((result) {
      result.fold(
            (failure) {
          // Handle error and emit a failure state
          emit(MapStateFailure("Error al obtener la información del usuario"));
          return;
        },
            (user) {
              List<StudentModel> studentModels = [];
              GetStudentsStopsRequest request = GetStudentsStopsRequest(school: "COLEGIO NOGALES", familyCode: user.familyCode);
              logger.info("Request: ${request.toJson()}");
              getStudentsUseCase.call(params: request).then((result) {
                logger.info(result.toString());
                result.fold(
                      (failure) {
                    // Handle error and emit a failure state
                    emit(MapStateFailure("Error al obtener la lista de estudiantes: ${failure.message}"));
                  },
                      (students) {
                    studentModels = students.map((student) {
                      return StudentModel.fromEntity(student);
                    }).toList();
                  },
                );

                if (studentModels.isEmpty){
                  emit(MapStateFailure("No se encontraron estudiantes"));
                }
                else{
                  emit(MapStateSuccess(studentModels));
                  emit(MapStateIdle());
                }
              }).catchError((e) {
                // Catch unexpected errors
                emit(MapStateFailure("Error inesperado: ${e.toString()}"));
              });
            },
      );
    }).catchError((e) {
      // Catch unexpected errors
      emit(MapStateFailure("Error inesperado: ${e.toString()}"));
      return;
    });


  }
  
  void showParadas(StudentModel paradas) {
    emit(MapStateLoadingStops());
   getParadasUseCase.call(params: paradas).then((result) {
      logger.info(result.toString());
      result.fold(
            (failure) {
          // Handle error and emit a failure state
          emit(MapStateFailure("Error al obtener la lista de paradas: ${failure.message}"));
        },
            (paradas) {
          emit(MapStateSuccessStops(paradas));
          emit(MapStateIdle());
        },
      );
    }).catchError((e) {
      // Catch unexpected errors
      emit(MapStateFailure("Error inesperado: ${e.toString()}"));
    });
  }

And finally BlocListener
BlocListener<MapStateCubit, MapState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is MapStateLoading) {
              LoadingDialog.show(context);
              debugPrint('Loading map data...');
              markerBusIcon = state.busIcon;
              markerCasaIcon = state.casaIcon;
              markerSchoolIcon = state.schoolIcon;
              context.read<MapStateCubit>().showMap();
            } else if (state is MapStateSuccess) {
              _stopTimer();
              LoadingDialog.hide(context);
              debugPrint('MapStateSuccess: ${state.students}');
              setState(() {
                selectedHijoString = state.students.first.nombre;
                _students.clear();
                _students.addAll(state.students);
                for (var student in _students) {
                  gpsHijos[student.nombre] = student.gps;
                }
                // Update markers
                _markers.clear();
                for (var student in _students) {
                  _markers.add(
                    Marker(
                      markerId: MarkerId(student.id),
                      position: LatLng(student.gps.latitude, student.gps.longitude),
                      infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                        title: student.nombre,
                        snippet: student.gps.idRfid,
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        showAboutDialog(context: context);
                        _moveCamera(student.gps.latLng, zoomIn: true);
                        logger.info('Marker tapped: ${student.nombre}');
                      },
                      icon: markerBusIcon!,
                    ),
                  );
                }
                context.read<MapStateCubit>().showParadas(_students.first);
              });
              _startLocationUpdateTimer();
            }
            else if(state is MapStateLoadingStops){
              _stopTimer();
              LoadingDialog.show(context);
              debugPrint('Loading paradas...');
            }
            else if (state is MapStateSuccessStops) {
              _stopTimer();
              LoadingDialog.hide(context);
              debugPrint('MapStateSuccessStops: ${state.stops}');
              _markers.removeWhere((marker) => marker.markerId.toString().contains('PARADA'));
              _paradas.clear();
              _paradas.addAll(state.stops);
              for (var parada in _paradas){
                _markers.add(
                  Marker(
                    markerId: MarkerId("PARADA ${parada.address}"),
                    position: LatLng(
                    double.parse(parada.latitude.toString()),
                    double.parse(parada.longitude.toString()),
                     ),
                    infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                    title: parada.address,
                    snippet: parada.address,
                    ),
                    ));
              setState(() {
                _addParadaMarker();
              });
              }}
            else if (state is MapStateIdle) {
              debugPrint('MapStateIdle');
              _startLocationUpdateTimer();
            }
            else if (state is MapStateFailure) {
              _stopTimer();
                showDialog(
                 context: context,
                 barrierDismissible: false, // Prevent dialog from closing by tapping outside
                  builder: (context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                    title: const Text('Error'),
                    content: const Text('No hay información'),
                    actions: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close the dialog
                      Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
                    },
                      child: const Text('Aceptar'),
                    ),
                    ],
                    );
                    },
                );
            }


Do you use Equatable in your State or Entity?

@ĐìnhNhật no I have it without any extends
